# SQL SELECT WHERE IN incremented ID

Tags: sql, filemaker

I need to increment a static value in a select like this

```
SELECT 'id-?' , field FROM table WHERE field IN (SELECT field FROM table2)
```

So the "?" means an upcounting number from 0 - x for the static value "id".

So the result should be like

```
id-1   AAA
id-2   BBB
id-3   CCC
```

Where  the first value (plus the counter) is a static value and the second is from the database.

Comment: What's the column name for the id-x values?

Comment: Easiest way to do this is use the Row_Number Function and con cat it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: There is no tag vor my DBS its Filemaker.

Answer (score 1):

*ROW_NUMBER is an invalid function* if used with FileMaker Pro **ExecuteSQL()**. The set of SQL functions is limited. The recommendation is to create a calculation = 
**Get ( RecordNumber )** 
and use that field in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
select field
        , 'id-' + convert(varchar(10), row_number() over (Order by field))
from table1 where field in (select field from table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want:

```
select ('id-' || cast(row_number() over order by field)) as id, field 
from table 
where field in (select field from table2);
```

This uses ANSI-standard syntax.  The specific syntax might vary depending on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this thread on FileMaker community: https://community.filemaker.com/thread/74404

You will need to add an extra calc field as mentioned by @user9669471

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT 'id-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY field)), field 
FROM table 
WHERE field IN (SELECT field FROM table2)
```